# Search all folders and subfolders

Tags: c#

I need to search on all folders and subfolders to find image files.
My problem is that I can not search on a network dir and with this code, it only find onde folder and not all folders and subfolders. Any help? Thank you.
What I have:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> filesList = new List<string>();
    // Create the new DataTable to be used
    tableWithPhotos = new DataTable();
    tableWithPhotos.Columns.Add("Nome e formato do ficheiro (duplo clique para visualizar a imagem)");
    tableWithPhotos.Columns.Add("Caminho ( pode ser copiado Ctrl+C )");
    var diretorios = new List<string>() {@"C:\Users\myfolder\pictures"};
    var extensoes = new List<string>() { "*.jpg", "*.bmp", "*.png", "*.tiff", "*.gif" };
    foreach (string entryExtensions in extensoes)
    {
        foreach (string entryDirectory in diretorios)
        {
        filesList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(entryDirectory, entryExtensions, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because you've specified the search option `TopDirectoryOnly`. Make it `AllDirectories`.

Comment: In one of your questions, you did have all ready the answer for this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984123/progressbar-on-search-button/51984790?noredirect=1#comment91075460_51984790 and I did put on comment for you for this specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is you're specifying `TopDirectoryOnly` for `SearchOptions`. It should be `AllDirectories`.

```
filesList.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(entryDirectory, entryExtensions, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

To add to the answer, I think you can simplify the process. Creating a list of strings with one directory doesn't make sense. I'm talking about this line:

```
var diretorios = new List<string>() {@"C:\Users\myfolder\pictures"};
```

Instead, do something like this:

```
var topDir = @"C:\Users\myfolder\pictures";
var extensoes = new List<string>() { "*.jpg", "*.bmp", "*.png", "*.tiff", "*.gif" };
foreach (string ext in extensoes)
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(topDir, ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    // Add to list.
}
```

I encourage the use of `EnumerateFiles()` instead of `GetFiles()` as it's faster especially if you have a large number if files. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5669635/302248) answer.

Comment: Ok. Good help. But I need to add all files to datatable:             `// And now here we will add all the files that it has found into the DataTable
            foreach (string entryFiles in filesList)
            {
                DataRow row = tableWithPhotos.NewRow();
                row[0] = Path.GetFileName(entryFiles);
                row[1] = entryFiles;
                tableWithPhotos.Rows.Add(row);
            }`

Comment: I think this can do what I want: `filesList.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(allDir, ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories));`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I need to do:

```html
filesList.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(allDir, ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```